# Permalinks linking to similar named site

Tags: menus, permalinks

I'm having a problem with the permalinks on a testing site linking to live site.

Basically the hosting company set up this separate site for testing so that edits could be made without affecting the live site. The only different between the URL of the testing site and the live site is that the testing site doesn't have "www." at the start and have "/wp" at the end.

So the problem is that for some reason when you click on the menu buttons it brings you to the main site. So if you click "Biography" in the menu, "www." is automatically added to the URL and sometimes the "/wp" is removed, although it doesn't seem to matter if it's not, and you get brought to the "Biography" page on the live site.

This makes it impossible to test any page except for the Home page. I've checked the permalinks in settings and they're correct. I've tried a few different things with the menu itself including adding each URL individually. I've also tried typing the URL of each page directly into the browser but I still get redirected to the main site even though I get to the Home page this way.

I'm using the Customizr theme and Wordpress 4.2.1

Answer (score -1):

Have you updated the links in your database? Are they still pointing to your live site?

Sorry, I will elaborate.

If you download your database you will see that the url for your live site will appear several times. For example:

```
INSERT INTO `wpfr_options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES
(1, 'siteurl', 'http://www.yourwebsite.com', 'yes'),
```

The quickest way to change these references to your live site is to do a search and replace for each instance of the old url.